# a malloc is not working for some reason

Tags: c, malloc, corrupt

I made a data type:

```
typedef struct Sale_t *Sale;
struct Sale_t
{
    int license;
    int km_min;
    int km_max;
    int price;
};
```

I am creating it with this function:

```
Sale saleCreate(int license, int km_min, int km_max, int price,List sales)
{
    if(saleFind(sales,license)==RENTAL_CAR_ALREADY_ON_SALE)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    if(km_min<0||km_max<=km_min||price<=0)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    Sale salePtr = malloc(sizeof(*salePtr));
    if(!salePtr)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    salePtr->license=license;
    salePtr->km_min=km_min;  //here it crashes
    salePtr->km_max=km_max;
    salePtr->price=price;
    return salePtr;
}
```

(Don't mind about `Sale` and `Sale_t`; I'm using a `typedef` in a header file so it's not a problem at all.)

After some testing, I have found out that if `salePtr->km_min` gets any integer other than `0`, the program crashes.

What causes this? I'm sure it's something to do with `malloc()`...

## EDIT

i made a similar data type which works PERFECTLY:

```
typedef struct Car_t *Car;
struct Car_t
{
    int license;
    char* name;
    int price;
    int km;
    int renterId;
};
Car carCreate(int license, char* name, int price, int km, List cars)
{
    if(carFind(cars,license)==RENTAL_CAR_ALREADY_EXISTS)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    if(km<0||price<=0)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    Car carPtr = malloc(sizeof(*carPtr));
    if(!carPtr)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    carPtr->km=km;
    carPtr->license=license;
    carPtr->name=name;
    carPtr->price=price;
    carPtr->renterId=0;
    return carPtr;
}
```

Comment: Please show the typedef for `Sale`.

Comment: We need more info ... what about `List`? Can you add a few `const` in pointer parameters of functions?

Comment: Ok, please post a complete, compilable example showing the problem.  From what I see here, `malloc()` should be returning the correct sized object.

Comment: saleCreate(6976,96,312,22,sales); for example crashes... never mind the lists and all that stuff, they work perfectly... even the Sale itself almost works, all the fields can save numbers except for km_min...

Comment: @Yanal: do you have any <s>stupid</s>lowercase `#define km_min ...` somewhere, maybe? Or some other thing equally <s>stupid</s>bad?

Comment: no :) i dont have any defines of it

Comment: A question occurs: how is malloc being pulled in? Are you including it from the proper headers? If not it's implicitly defined as returning an int (which is wrong) and may cause you a lot of grief.

Comment: Yep ... @Yanal: increase the warning level of your compiler and **mind the warnings**. @Chris may be on the right track ...

Comment: i am including it from the proper headers. to ease you in helpin me, i will inform you that there is a similar data type to Sale which works perfectley

Comment: There are only a few options, they aren't pretty. One, it's a preprocessor thing (as pmb) suggested. Two, you've got some genuine memory corruption at work. Three malloc is returning as an int, so you're not writing to the correct memory location. That's all I can think of.

Comment: none of the options dont apply i think... i CAN create Sale types and i can even set their fields, except for km_min...

Comment: I think everything is fine. Can you test with a different name: try `km_minimum` instead.

Comment: lol i tried those tricks, they dont work! you must understand that km_min cant get any number except 0. any other number makes it crash for some reason. the other fields works fine, i dont know whats wrong here

Comment: @Yanal: your code works well [at ideone](http://ideone.com/UWLyK).

Comment: it doesnt work at my Eclipse, and at our server's SSH valgrind it runs but it doesnt print the Sales

Answer (score 4):

This is wrong:

```
Sale salePtr = malloc(sizeof(*salePtr));
```

Should (probably) be:

```
Sale *salePtr = malloc(sizeof(Sale));
```

I say probably because you're using `Sale` which you don't define in the code you've pasted, so it may be typedef'd to a pointer type already.

**EDIT**

Since the OP has typedef'd Sale to Sale_t*, it should look like this:

```
Sale salePtr = malloc(sizeof(Sale_t));
```

Comment: im using this: typedef struct Sale_t *Sale; i have edited the OP

Comment: @edit of Chris. it doesnt compile that way. you guys should understand that the other fields work perfectly, its just the km_min that doesnt work...

Comment: Are you really defining the typedef ABOVE your struct?

Comment: `sizeof(*salePtr)` will have the sme value as `sizeof(Sale_t)` if `salePtr` is a `struct Sale_t*`.

Comment: its not above, its in another file, i just copied it there to show you what is happening... the only problem here is with km_min. the rest work perfectly

Answer (score 3):

This line is wrong:

```
Sale salePtr = malloc(sizeof(*salePtr));
```

You used an identifier `salePtr`, before it was defined (or well, in the definition itself). This should work:

```
Sale salePtr = malloc(sizeof(*Sale));
```

However, since we are actually allocating memory for a `Sale_t` this seems more logical to me:

```
Sale salePtr = malloc(sizeof(Sale_t));
```

Comment: im doing this earlier: typedef struct Sale_t *Sale;

Comment: the usage `sizeof *ptr` (or with redundant parenthesis `sizeof(*ptr)`) is perfectly correct and, arguably, better than `sizeof (TYPE)` because there is no need to change the `sizeof` operand if the type of the object changes.

Answer (score 0):

Since the OP mentions that

```
typedef Sale_t* Sale
```

was used, here is what needs to be done

Use this for alloc

```
Sale salePtr = (Sale)malloc(sizeof(Sale));
```

Use this for return

```
return salePtr;
```

Comment: @Pavan: casting the return value of `malloc` is redundant and very likely indicates an error **in C**, and the usage `sizeof *ptr` (or with redundant parenthesis `sizeof(*ptr)`) is perfectly correct and, arguably, better than `sizeof (TYPE)` because there is no need to change the `sizeof` operand if the type of the object changes.

Comment: also Sale_t is not recognized inside the saleCreate function

Comment: In C, the struct type must be referred to by its full name: `struct Sale_t`. *I believe C++ accepts the struct tag alone to refer to the type: `Sale_t`*

Comment: @pmg, I understand the redundtant part, but I do not understand why it would *error in C*.

Comment: @Pavan: it errors when `void*` and `int` are treated differently by the compiler (different size; different passing conventions (`void*` in a register; `int` on the stack), ...). The cast tells the compiler to not worry about that; that **YOU** know best.

Comment: @pmg, were you referring to my typo where I cast the output of malloc to *(Sale_t)* instead of *(Sale_t *)*?

Comment: No @Pavan. `malloc` returns a `void*`. Without a prototype, the compiler assumes it returns a `int` ... and must issue a diagnostic if you assign that `int` to any pointer variable ... unless you ask it to shut up with the cast. If `int`s and `void*`s have different representations, you've hidden the error.

Comment: @pmg Interesting, I did not know that. I come from performance improvement background, and believe me, we hack whatever we can to get things to run faster :). Nice to have a new perspective. Thanks for being patient.

Comment: hehe no problem @Pavan, just remember many casts in C are suspicious: the compiler can do the conversions itself with no "help" from the programmer.